# Display Images in Android GridView after fetching images from database

Tags: android, eclipse, android-gridview

I am trying to display images in Android `Gridview` dynamically after fetching the data from a sqlite database. I tried with `ImageAdapter` examples but I've had no success with it. Can anyone help me, how to fetch the data and pass it to the `ImageAdapter.getView()` method so that it will display the images?
Below is my source
1.Fetching of the data from db

```
private void fun_FecthData() {


    Cursor cur = db.query(false, "goodsmgnt1", new String[]{ "itemimage"}, null,null,
            null, null, null, null);
    //Toast.makeText(mContext.getApplicationContext(), "No of Image = " + cur.getCount(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
if (cur.getCount() < 1) {
    cur.close();

}
cur.moveToFirst();

for (int i = 0; i < cur.getCount(); i++) {

    byte[] itemimgblob = cur.getBlob(cur.getColumnIndex("itemimage"));
    Bitmap itemImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(itemimgblob, 0, itemimgblob.length);
        img_bitmap.add(itemImage);//Image stored in Bitmap array List

            cur.moveToNext();

        }

db.close();

ImageAdapter Getview()

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ImageView imageView;

    if (convertView == null) {

        // if it’s not recycled, initialize some attributes
        Toast.makeText(mContext.getApplicationContext(), "Getview if " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);

        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200, 200));

        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(mContext.getApplicationContext(), "Getview else " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;

    }

    File imgFile = new File(img_bitmap.get(position).toString());



    if(imgFile.exists()){


        Toast.makeText(mContext.getApplicationContext(), "Getview Position = " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());



        imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);



    }

    return imageView;

}


}
```

Comment: The code shows us how you download an image. Do you also have the code for the adapter? Can you give us a html-link to `ImageAdapter example`?

Answer (score 0):

In android displaying an item with an image in a list or grid works like this (example):

- The grid needs to display item that is at position #35
- The grid asks its adapter for a filled griditemview for the item that is at position #35
- griditemview is either recycled from an old griditemview that is not visible any more or a new griditemview is created
- each griditemview has a corresponding viewHolder with imageID and a bitmap-gui element
- the image in the griditemview is initally loaded with a placeholder-image that will  be visible until the imagload is complete.
- the adapter initiates loading the image in the background (async-task) that gets the viewHolder with imageID.
- when loading of the image in the background is finished the viewholder-gui element gets the loaded image.

Here is a working example from [APhotoManager](https://github.com/k3b/APhotoManager). It contains a [GalleryCursorFragment](https://github.com/k3b/APhotoManager/blob/FDroid/app/src/main/java/de/k3b/android/androFotoFinder/gallery/cursor/GalleryCursorFragment.java) with the gridview and a [GalleryCursorFragment](https://github.com/k3b/APhotoManager/blob/FDroid/app/src/main/java/de/k3b/android/androFotoFinder/gallery/cursor/GalleryCursorFragment.java) with an embedded GridCellViewHolder